Access ROS Message value by string name (C++, ROS2)
(ROS2 humble, C++, Linux environment)
Use case: I want to build some thresholds for certain values in messages (multiple fields, message types, topics). I want to be able to configure the threshold at runtime, so however that looks, ultimately it's a string field name and some threshold configuration. Furthermore, I'd like to keep this flexible, be able to add new field thresholds to my config without having to recompile code (including and especially if new fields are added to a message).
My immediate thought on how to solve that use case is to have some way to look up the value in a message by a field name double get_value(const MsgT& msg, const std::string& field_name); (ignoring the field type for a moment).
high cost solution: One way to solve the problem is to use the YAML conversion methods to make a string, load that into yaml-cpp, and then inspect the YAML object. That feels like an unnecessarily costly approach (I'm not super resource constrained on this operation, but this seems excessive).
unergonomic solution: After a lot of digging around in rosidl, I have the starts of a design using the rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp library. But I feel like the developer ergonomics here are pretty bad; which, to me, is a smell that I'm not using them the right way or that there's a better way to be doing what I want to do.
I see some related problems/solutions for even more generic cases - often ones where you lack the message definition or library. But I have those both, so I feel like I should be able to leverage the knowledge of what the message is (and I can, with the 'unergonomic' solution, which encourages me that there's a better solution out there still).
Question - Is there a better library/tool to access message fields by a string name?

It is not entirely clear to me what exactly you want to do, but maybe message_filters can be relevant in this context?
